# Linux freezes after reboot/shutdown

Tags: kali-linux, shutdown, reboot, freeze

I'm running a Kali Linux with KDE Plasma and encountered an issue where I cannot logout/reboot or shutdown.

I tried adding `acpi=force`, `apm=power_off'` and `reboot=bios` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, but it didn't work.

The issue is that whenever I try to shutdown or reboot the PC it freezes, the cursor dissapears and the screen remains frozen basically forever. I had the absolutely same problem with GNOME before and that's the main reason I decided to switch to KDE Plasma, but it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Please note that Kali is a tool [designed for experts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399626/why-is-kali-linux-so-hard-to-set-up-why-wont-people-help-me). It is not a normal operating system and should not be used as one. You're trying to customize Kali, so I would strongly urge you to use a different operating system.